# Is there a way to add the first element of one array to the first two elements of another array using iteration in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I want to add the elements of two arrays together, one is called `propensity` shape = `(4,)` and length = `4` and the other is called `state_change_lambda` with shape `(3,)` and length `3`.

But I want to add the first element of `state_change_lambda` to the first and second element of `propensity` and then continue adding the element wise like a normal iteration after that.

something like:

```
propensity = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4,])
state_change_lambda = np.array([5, 6, 7])
[out]: new_array_after_addition = ([6, 7, 9, 11]) <-- five has been added to both element 1 and 2 of propensity
```

Only I'm not too sure how to do this in python, I've had a look at `enumerate` but I'm not sure thats quite the right thing to use

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the first addition specially, and the rest through a view:

```
propensity[0] += state_change_lambda[0]
propensity[1:] += state_change_lambda
```

If you don't want to increment `propensity` in-place, you have some options.

One way is to add an extended array:

```
result = propensity + np.concatenate((state_change_lambda[:1], state_change_lambda))
```

Another way (which I personally prefer, is to pre-allocate the result and store into it:

```
result = propensity.copy()
result[0] += state_change_lambda[0]
result[1:] += state_change_lambda
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the difference of the lengths of the two arrays:

```
propensity = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4,])
state_change_lambda = np.array([5, 6, 7])

length = len(propensity) - len(state_change_lambda) + 1
for i in range(len(propensity)):
    if i < length:
        propensity[i] += state_change_lambda[0]
    else:
        propensity[i] += state_change_lambda[i-length+1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions work but I'm trying to avoid using to many loops